# Dynamic OptionMenu or other options in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, pyad

We are trying to make a simple GUI for our HR department.  We are using tkinter with PyAD and subprocess.
I am trying to create a dynamic OptionMenu based on a "selection" in the previous OptionMenu.

For example: "Department" OptionMenu {"Warehouse", "Office", "Shipping"} >>> The "Job" OptionMenu would change accordingly  "Warehouse" is selected "Job" OptionMenu would show {"Pallet Jack", "High Lift", "Stand Up"}.

I have hard coded the warehouse positions due to that department having the most hires.

```
depts = { 'Warehouse','Office','HR','IT','Maintenance'}
dept_var.set('DEPT') # set the default option


jobs = {'Pallet Jack', 'General Labor', 'Sit Down', 'Stand Up', 'Highlift'}
job_var.set('JOB')

popupMenu1 = OptionMenu(mainframe, dept_var, *depts)

popupMenu1.grid(row = 2, column =1)

popupMenu2 = OptionMenu(backframe, job_var, *jobs)

popupMenu2.grid(row = 2, column =1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `command` option to `popupMenu1` and do  the changes for `popupMenu2` in this command function, as follows:

```
popupMenu1 = OptionMenu(root, dept_var, *depts, command=change_job_menu)
```

and the function `change_job_menu` as:

```
def change_job_menu(value):
    popupMenu2['menu'].delete(0, END)

    if dept_var.get() == 'Warehouse':
        new_menu = {"Pallet Jack", "High Lift", "Stand Up"}
        for i in new_menu:
            popupMenu2['menu'].add_command(label=i, command=tk._setit(job_var, i))
```

Comment: please accept the answer so that the question can be closed